# Signed App Bluetooth doesn't work

Tags: android, bluetooth, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-keystore

My application connects with a device over RFComm Bluetooth channel. All is working from android 4.4.2 to 5.x.

According to the Android 6.0 documentation, I added `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission to the application manifest, and ask the user for dangerous permission.

During the debug session all seems to work properly, I can discover, pair, connect to my device, send a receive data, without issues.

When I sign the app with the keystore I can't make the app working.

I tested on those devices:

- htc m9 with Android 6.0
- Nexus 5x with Android 6.0
- Nexus 5x with Android 6.0.1

Any idea what is causing this and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance,

**UPDATE:** looking on the LogCat I found this `04-01 14:09:43.339 4851-4912/? W/ActivityManager: Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{d19eff7 u0 it.centrosistemi.ambrogioremote/it.centrosistemi.ambrogiocore.library.communication.bluetooth.BluetoothPickerActivity t110 f}`.

I made some searchs with keyword: **Activity destroy timeout**, but I didn't find a fix. :(